# General term of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

$$1, -\frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{5}, -\frac{6}{7}, \ldots$$

Find the general term for the sequence above, and determine whether the sequence is convergent or divergent.

I tried to figure out the denominator should be $2n-1$. The alternating $-1$ should be $(-1)^{n+1}$. But I cannot figure out the numerator sequences to generate the general term for the whole sequences.

Comment: If you had figured out the denominator, surely you can figure out the numerator as it is _simpler_.  Think the same way.

Comment: it is 1,2,4,6. it is not arithmetic.

Comment: Let the sequence start from the second term instead.  Then append $1$ outside the sequence.  Where does this question come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like
$$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{0^{n-1}+2n-2}{2n-1} $$
or a bit simpler if you start indexing at $n=0$:
$$a_n=(-1)^{n}\frac{0^{n}+2n}{2n+1}.$$
Of course it could also be 
$$ a_n=(-1)^n\frac{0^n+(2n\bmod 17)}{(2n\bmod 42)+1}$$
or 
$$a_n=(-1)^n2^{1-\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}} 3^{-\sin\frac{n\pi}2}5^{\cos\frac{n\pi }2\sin(n\pi)}7^{\sin\frac{n\pi}2\sin((n-1)\pi)}$$

Comment: excellent.. thanks...

Comment: i think second one is easier to prove convergence. however, thx for all the alternative solutions

Comment: it's not convergence. Am i right? because both the subsequence is towards -1 and the another one is -1